# Spring @Transactional - Rollback is not happening

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions

I am new to spring and working on a sample program using Spring jdbc. this is to check how spring @Trsactional working and rolling back the changes to the Db if there is an exception.

But I am not able to achieve this. Through I am raising an exception in one of the DB update, still it's inserting the data to DB and not rolling back for that batch. For ex. after inserting 5000 I am raising an exception, so ideally it should rollback all the changes(for the current batch) to all the tables and total rows in Db should be 4000.

I know somewhere I am making mistake but not able to figure it out. Not sure if this is a correct approach.

I tried all possible ways available in the Internet, but still no luck. please help me to resolve this issue.

> **Here is my sample application  https://github.com/rajarshp/JavaSample**

**Code Snippet**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void executeDB(int count) throws Exception
    {

                CreateAccount newacc = new CreateAccount(jdbcTemplate);
                CreateUser newusr = new CreateUser(jdbcTemplate);
                //BalanceUpdate newbal = new BalanceUpdate(jdbcTemplate);
                newacc.addList(acclist);
                newusr.addToList(usrlist);
                //newbal.addList(ballist);

                newusr.execute(); // insert data to db
                newacc.addAccount(); // insert data to db
                //newbal.addBalance(); // insert data to db

                newacc.getAccList().clear();
                newusr.getUserList().clear();
                //newbal.getBalanceList().clear();
                if(count == 5000)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    throw new Exception("Rollback");
                }
                count += 1000;
                //throw new Exception();


        }
```

**XML:**

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"></context:component-scan>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
  <property name="username" value="system" />
  <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>


<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="startit" class="com.example.springtransaction.GlobalClass">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="dbupdate" class="com.example.springtransaction.DbUpdate">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Your `@Transactional` is useless. You are doing an internal method call. Spring AOP uses proxies so only method calls going into the object will pass through the proxy, not internal method calls.

Comment: @M. Deinum  would you mind to tell me which portion of the code I need to change for this please ? As I am a bit confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create bean for all Db operation classes like createUser or Cretae account in the xml file. remove the initialization on these classes from db operation class and use setter method to inject it from the xml. Post that call your db operation method. It should work.

```xml
<bean id="newaccount" class="com.example.springtransaction.CreateAccount">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean> 
<bean id="newuser" class="com.example.springtransaction.CreateUser">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean> 
<bean id="dbupdate" class="com.example.springtransaction.DbUpdate">  
<property name="newaccount" ref="newacc"></property>  
<property name="newuser" ref="newusr"></property>  
</bean>
```